# How can dreamweaver connect to the google cloud to upload pages

Tags: ssl, ftp, cloud, dreamweaver

I want Dreamweaver to upload pages to the google cloud I just obtained. ( I know dreamweaver is not a favorite but that's what I used to build a large site.) So I'd like to plug in the the google cloud and upload the pages I already have. 
What protocol can I use and how would I configure it.

FTP, SFTP ( with or without SSL) ?

Comment: Dreamweaver is a html building tool. Why you want to upload upload pages to the google cloud by dreamveaver?

Comment: OK , I'm new to cloud and mobile . I was under the impression that the google cloud can host html pages as well as PHP and mobile apps.The project I'm working on will use mobile apps to gather data and html with PHP for web browser viewing.

Comment: I guess I should start by asking...Can the Google cloud be used as a web server as well as everything else?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know this as well. Dreamweaver is also an FTP program, not just an HTML app. Can you configure Google Cloud Platform to DWs FTP so that it it becomes easy to transfer files back and forth. DW does have an SFTP option as well?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found out. Phonegap build is an Abobe version that compiles the apps on their server. So I doubt it can be used in the Google cloud. Dreamweaver can't connect, from what I have seen, to the Google cloud either. In any event Dreamweaver is probably not the best choice if I want to use the Google cloud. You could however probably use the straight phonegap from phonegap.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new site on dreamweaver an do not enter any server info. Also create a local folder To hold you web files.
Then open your google cloud console, open your bucket, click upload files or upload folder that’s all!